# Strategy for a Nim variation game - StoneGameStrategist - SRM 309

Tags: c++, game-theory, olpc

I'm fairly new to game theory and have understood only normal nim game where you remove stones from piles with **no condition** and the last player to remove wins. But then I came across a nice problem while reading [Game theory tutorial on Topcoder](https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=6239&rd=9989). The gist is as below:

> You and a friend are playing a game in which you take turns removing stones from piles. Initially, every pile has at least as many stones as the pile to its left. This property must be maintained throughout the game. On each turn, you remove one or more stones from a single pile. You and your friend alternate turns until it is no longer possible to make a valid move. The last player to have made a move wins the game. Note that if you remove all the stones from a pile, it is still considered a pile.
>   You are said to have made a "winning move" if after making that move, you can eventually win no matter what your friend does. You are given a int[] piles representing the number of stones in each pile from left to right. It is your turn to move. Find a winning move and return it as a String formatted as "TAKE s STONES FROM PILE k" (quotes for clarity only), where s and k (a 0-based index) are each integers with no leading zeros. If there are multiple winning moves, choose the one that minimizes s. If there is still a tie, choose the one that minimizes k. If no winning move is possible, return the String "YOU LOSE" (quotes for clarity only).

Removal of stones here has a condition such that you need to maintain the overall non-decreasing order, which is becoming a roadblock for me in coming up with a logic. I tried reading the [editorial](https://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=match_editorials&d2=srm309) for that, but unfortunately couldn't grasp the idea behind it. Can anyone please explain the solution in a more simple terms?

Answer (score 0):

The editorial does not explain how to solve the original game of Nim, but only provides a link to the Wikipedia page (where the solution can be found).

The editorial just explains how to map the Topcoder problem to that of a regular game of Nim:

First, the game can be transformed into one where the piles have the difference between the original piles (so the 3 6 6 example becomes 3 3 0).

Then the order of the piles is reversed (so the example becomes 0 3 3).

Then a move in this new game becomes a two-step process: remove stones from one pile and add it to the previous one (in the example, the winning move takes 3 from the last and add them to the middle pile, becoming 0 6 0).

Then if you just look at the odd-numbered piles (#1, #3, #5, etc), you get the regular game of Nim, and can apply a documented algorithm on that (so 0 3 3 is the same as a Nim position of 0 3).

The given explanation for that is thus:

any move on an odd-numbered pile becomes just like a move in the normal game of Nim;

any move on an even-numbered pile can be negated by just moving the same number of stones from the receiving odd-numbered pile to the next even-numbered pile (so the same losing position can be imposed again on the player).

Comment: Did that make sense? Or do you need more clarification?